# Ag-grid: several columns responsiveness problem

Tags: angular, ag-grid, responsiveness

I have a simple table with just 2 columns. By default, they do not fit the whole table width in a desktop view (they take just about 20% of the whole grid size). So I have to call `sizeColumnsToFit` method to expand them for the whole table size:

```
onGridReady(params): void {
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    ...
}
```

and everything looks fine after that. But, on mobile view, those columns exceed the screen size, so the grid tries to fit the columns by cutting the text and adding dots (...). While I want to have a horizontal scroll for mobile views instead, just like `autoSizeColumns` method would do.

For now I see 2 solutions

1. Determine which device this is and call an appropriate method -
   seems like a huge overflow for such silly problem.
2. `dirty patching` by modifying table
   css, which may result in unexpected behavior.

The question is - is there some simple solution of how to expand columns for large screen and have a horizontal scroll for a small screen?

Comment: Can you share the code of the column definition also, or preferably a working stackBlitz demo.